# How to Delete resources using Transaction

Tags: hl7-fhir

I would like to delete multiple resources by using a transaction, but I can't find any example nor information how resources should be marked in the bundle for delete.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by adding a `<deleted-entry>` Atom entry to the transaction Bundle, much like it's done when returning a Resource's history (which can contain deletions as well).

You can find information about it here: http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/xml.html#atom-deleted. It's actually a pretty recent addition to the Atom specification (see http://www.rfc-base.org/rfc-6721.html for more information).

The Java reference implementation has a setDeleted() on AtomEntry to make that work.

Comment: and here for JSON: http://hl7.org/implement/standards/fhir/json.html#json-bundle-delete

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answer.
I've managed to delete my posted Composition resource by using such code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>Delete in Transaction</title>
    <id>1181060367157445874</id>
    <updated>2014-04-28T15:48:16.863+03:00</updated>
    <deleted-entry xmlns="http://purl.org/atompub/tombstones/1.0" ref="http://spark.furore.com/fhir/Composition/19843313"/>
</feed>
```

`

Comment: Accepting your own answer to your questions is bad form.  It discourages people from answering your next question.